# How to find the common circle of two spheres?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, spheres

**Question**: Find the center and radius of common circle of the two spheres $x^2+y^2+z^2-x+z-2=0\,$ and $\,3(x^2+y^2)-8x-10y+8z+14=0$.

It is observed that the two spheres are orthogonal. But I am not able to find their common circle. It may be easy but I am not getting any idea. Can some one please throw a hint?

Comment: $3(x^2+y^2)-8x-10y+8z+14=0$ does *not* define a sphere.

Comment: But the condition of orthogonality is satisfied. May be the question is wrong.

Comment: Question may have been mistyped.  $3(x^2+y^2+z^2)$ in the second eqn maybe?

Comment: What "condition of orthogonality" are you refering to? What does it mean for two spheres to be "orthogonal"? In any case, the problem says nothing about "orthogonality", but asks for the intersection of the two spheres, (except that as stated, the second is a cone, not a sphere - please investigate to see if you have copied the equation correctly).

Comment: Regardless of how orthogonality is defined, why do you think it's important to finding the intersection?

Comment: @San Have you solved this problem yet? Are you still interested in an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Plane of intersection of these two spheres $S_1$ and $S_2$ is found by $S_1-S_2=0$ which in this case comes out to be $x+2y-z=4$ after simplification. Centre of $S_1= O(1/2,0,-1/2)$ and $S_2=P(4/3,5/3,-4/3)$. Now Equation of line OP is given by $(x-1/2)/1=(y-0)/2=(z+1/2)/-1$
Now, let centre of common circle C be $(r+1/2,2r,-r-1/2)$ as it will lie on this line OP. 
Since Centre lie on plane of intersection $x+2y-z=4$ so solving we get, $r=1/2$
Hence centre $C = (1,1,-1)$.